# TS2474 (TS) In 'const' enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression

Tags: .net, angular, typescript

Error code:

```
export declare const enum JSDocTagName {
    Desc = "desc",
    Id = "id",
    Meaning = "meaning",
}
```

Using Angular 6 with .net framework

Comment: Can't reproduce the error. Works fine in playground: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20declare%20const%20enum%20JSDocTagName%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Desc%20%3D%20%22desc%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Id%20%3D%20%22id%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Meaning%20%3D%20%22meaning%22%2C%0D%0A%7D

Comment: Just remove the declare keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constant enums are erased during transpilation, so they leave no code behind them in the runtime app. All uses are substituted for the value throughout the app. Therefore, your `declare` keyword is redundant:

```
export const enum JSDocTagName {
    Desc = "desc",
    Id = "id",
    Meaning = "meaning"
}
```

Unlike normal enums, constant enums can't have certain kinds of calculated values, for example, this is allowed in normal enums, but not constant enums:

```
const x = 1;

enum A {
    Name = x,
    Age = x + 1
}
```

Your error would normally be because you are trying to do something *like* the above on a constant enum.

You can use some calculated values even in a constant enum - as long as the result is predictable, such as:

```
const enum A {
    Name = 1 << 0,
    Age = 1 << 1,
    Date = 1 << 2
}
```